# Heroku Forcing Me to Push Gemfile Each Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have a requirement in my Rails application (3.0.7) for the gem yajl-ruby. For some weird reason, every time I do a push, Heroku (Bamboo stack) doesn't recognize that the gem is listed in my gemfile.

So what happens is that my application crashes each time I do not push the gemfile. To fix this, I need to change something in my gemfile (like add a character to a comment or something inconsequential like that) and push the gemfile to Heroku again (even though there were no gem changes).  It doesn't make sense because when I close from my Heroku git (even when the app is in a crashed state), the gemfile is fine, with yajl-ruby in there.

Has anyone else ever had a similar issue? I'm trying to figure out why this is and how it can be rectified so I don't need to keep making these small changes to my gemfile and pushing it?

Comment: This not the answer you are looking for, but maybe has a clue in it: I was using RubyMine to create the whole project and got that same problem. After many atempts I created my project from the terminal with cygwin and it works just find. It seems to be related with the Gemfile.lock when it is generated for windows. a bug that both, bundler and heroku teams are aware of.

Comment: oh, but i thought that if the gemfile.lock is generated for windows it is now skipped altogether.http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler .  maybe you had this issue awhile ago?

Comment: Yep. It is ignored alright. But still, heroku behaves normally only works when I create the project from cygwin. I'm a newbie to rails and currently trying to learn it. As soon as I finish with some other stuff I'm doing I will try to understand this better and update here. For the meantime, I'd suggest you to make the experiment :)